# Dynamically loaded input field on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

At the moment I have a list of strings I am getting from the database. I then loop through these strings with a `foreach` statement and print them within their own `<li></li>`.

When I click on a `<li>` I have a jQuery event which triggers. It gets the string from within the `<li></li>` and places it within an input field value, up until now it still works fine.

Though, when I click within the input field the text value disappears and also I am unable to get the input field to `focus` and it doesn't allow me to type.

My questions are: why is my input value disappearing and why is it not allowing me to type anything within the input field?

Code below:

HTML **before click**

```
<li id="list_item-47" class="sortableList" data-id="47">
    The Title
    <br>
    <br>
</li>
```

HTML **after click**

```
<li id="list_item-47" class="sortableList" data-id="47">
    <input type="text" class="inputField" value="The Title">
    <div class="updateLink" data-id="47"></div>
</li>
```

HTML **after focus**

```
<li id="list_item-47" class="sortableList" data-id="47">
    <input type="text" class="inputField" value>
    <div class="updateLink" data-id="47"></div>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".sortableList").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var list_item = $(this).text();
    var data_id = $(this).data('id');       

    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="inputField" value="' + list_item + '"></input><div class="updateLink" data-id="' + data_id + '"></div>');       

    return false;

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing <br> tag and extra spaces from <li> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is disappearing because the input that you create is within a .sortableList span, and that span has a click event attached to it. So when you click on the input, you're triggering the click event, which replaces the contents of that li with an empty text box.

A quick fix would be to add this inside your click function:

```
$(this).off('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8D9VY/

You'll still need to handle what when you want to save what's in the text field, though, and then turn that click event back on if you want to modify the value again...

Comment: Yep just tested that out and it's working for me, thanks for your help!!